# as3 navigation - gotoAndPlay script not working consistently

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I think I've made an error in logic somewhere but can't find it, I have a movie clip which contains 4 further animated movieclips, each with stop() actions at specific frames, and 2 buttons, 1 to move left and another to move right, the animations work as expected if the user clicks say right, right, right, right, left, left, left, left for the first time, but then things stop evaluating properly.

Am using switch case statements on a variable to pick out the mc to animate, would I be better of using an If Else statement? Heres my code, as may be obvious actionscript is not my forte!

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.events.Event;

import fl.text.TLFTextField;

import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

// Global variables
var mcWidth:int = 768;
var mcPosInc:int = 0;
var boxAnimPlay:int = 1;
var mcMoving:Boolean = false;
var buttonClicked:String = "right";
var mcLeft;
var mcRight;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);

// frame Handler
function frameHandler(event:Event):void
{
// Initialize button click events
controlGrp.bttn_left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goLeft); 
controlGrp.bttn_right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goRight);

function goLeft(e:MouseEvent):void {
buttonClicked = "left";
// change position
if (mcPosInc > 0 && mcMoving == false) {
    mcMoving = true;
    mcPosInc --;
    boxAnimPlay --;
    // Scroll mc1
    mcLeft = new Tween(mc1, "x", Regular.easeOut, mc1.x, mc1.x + mcWidth, 1.5, true);
    mcLeft.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, end);
    function end(event:TweenEvent) {
        mcMoving = false;
    }

    if (boxAnimPlay >= 1) {
    switch (boxAnimPlay) {
        case 3:
            mc1.box4.gotoAndPlay(17);
            mc1.box3.gotoAndPlay(31);
        break;
        case 2:
            mc1.box2.gotoAndPlay(31);
            mc1.box3.gotoAndPlay(46);
        break;
        case 1:
            mc1.box1.gotoAndPlay(17);
            mc1.box2.gotoAndPlay(46);
        break;
        }
    }

    trace(boxAnimPlay);
    trace(buttonClicked);
}
}
}

// Play movie tests
function goRight(e:MouseEvent):void {
buttonClicked = "right";
// change position
if (mcPosInc < 3 && mcMoving == false) {
    mcMoving = true;
    mcPosInc ++;
    boxAnimPlay ++;
    // Scroll mc1
    mcRight = new Tween(mc1, "x", Regular.easeOut, mc1.x, mc1.x - mcWidth, 1.5, true);
    mcRight.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, end);
    function end(event:TweenEvent) {
        mcMoving = false;
    }
if (boxAnimPlay <= 4) {
switch (boxAnimPlay) {
    case 1:

    break;
    case 2:
        mc1.box1.gotoAndPlay(1);
        mc1.box2.gotoAndPlay(1);
    break;
    case 3:
        mc1.box2.gotoAndPlay(16);
        mc1.box3.gotoAndPlay(1);
    break;
    case 4:
        mc1.box3.gotoAndPlay(16);
        mc1.box4.gotoAndPlay(1);
    break;
    }
}

    trace(boxAnimPlay);
    trace(buttonClicked);
}   

// Add Text Labels to TitleGroup
switch (boxAnimPlay) {
    case 1:
        readout.text = "test";
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, basically the frames I was targeting in the gotoAndPlay contained stop() statements, once I targeted the subsequent frames, ie

Instead of:

```
switch (boxAnimPlay) {
    case 3:
        mc1.box4.gotoAndPlay(17);
        mc1.box3.gotoAndPlay(31);
    break;
    case 2:
        mc1.box2.gotoAndPlay(31);
        mc1.box3.gotoAndPlay(46);
    break;
    case 1:
        mc1.box1.gotoAndPlay(17);
        mc1.box2.gotoAndPlay(46);
    break;
    }
```

I used this:

```
switch (boxAnimPlay) {
    case 3:
        mc1.box4.gotoAndPlay(17);
        mc1.box3.gotoAndPlay(32); // no stop on subsequent frame
    break;
    case 2:
        mc1.box2.gotoAndPlay(32); // no stop on subsequent frame
        mc1.box3.gotoAndPlay(47); // no stop on subsequent frame
    break;
    case 1:
        mc1.box1.gotoAndPlay(17);
        mc1.box2.gotoAndPlay(47); // no stop on subsequent frame
    break;
    }
```